# how to do a rendertransform on control but not content/children?

Tags: wpf-controls

I'm trying to make a specific control smaller, without making its content smaller..

If I use Control.Rendertransform, child content will be transformed as well..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick was, **not** to use a RenderTransform, but in my case, use a *LayoutTransform* instead.